# Entity framework how to include a 1=>0,1 in a many-to-many relationship in my model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I am trying to figure out either with code first or with db first how to get a model that will represent this situation. I am using entity framework 5.0.

I have a User that may or may not have a single account associated with them.
If they are related to an account they will have many roles.

Essentially, I Need:

User ==> 0,1 UserAccount 1 ==> * UserAccountRole * <== 1 AccountRole

The UserAccount Table needs a unique Key on UserID
The UserAccount Table has a primary key of UserID,AccountID
The UserAccountRole has a Primary key of UserID,AccountID,AccountRoleId

When I use DB First, the model does not pick up the 1=>0,1 
In the code first I cannot figure out the Fluent API way to represent this:

[image]

Can I do this, or do I need a Many to Many User Account table with a business rule of just one?

Thanks

Comment: I see what you're wanting now, sorry.  Is this a legacy DB?  Its not possible to create a join table on a 1:many relationship, and it's generally considered best practice to map the association on one of the entities - in this case, having a UserId on your Accounts table.

Comment: No, this is not legacy, I was trying to figure out if Entity could figure it out.  I believe from an RI standpoint the model above is correct.  If I make put accountID in the user table then there is the potential for roles without an account.  I think I have to go with a many to many and just have special knowledge that it is really a 1=>0 or 1.   Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,  I have found the answer, it is a bit involved so I am not sure if I like it.

To get the table structure above you have to create SystemUserAccount as a Many to Many.  Then you need to create a separate unique Key on the UserId column of the SystemUserAccount table.  The only hook I could find to run this was on the Seed method of the DBInitializer.  Here is the code:

```
public  class SystemUser
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; } 

  public ICollection<SystemUserAccount> SystemUserAccounts{get;set;}
}

 public class Account
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public ICollection<SystemUserAccount> SystemUserAccount { get; set; }
}

public class SystemUserAccount
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AccountRole> AccountRoles { get; set; }

    public SystemUser SystemUser { get; set; }
    public Account UserAccount { get; set; }
}

public class AccountRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SystemUserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

Then this Context:

```
 public DbSet<SystemUser> SystemUser { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SystemUserAccount> SystemUserAccount { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Account> Account { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AccountRole> AccountRole { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SystemUserAccount>()
            .HasKey(sua => new { sua.UserId, sua.AccountId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<SystemUserAccount>()
            .HasRequired(sua => sua.SystemUser)
            .WithMany(u => u.SystemUserAccounts)
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SystemUserAccount>()
            .HasMany(sua => sua.AccountRoles)
            .WithMany(ar => ar.UserAccounts)
            .Map(m =>
                     {
                         m.ToTable("UserAccountRole");
                         m.MapLeftKey("UserId", "AccountId");
                         m.MapRightKey("AccountRoleId");
                     }
            );
    }
```

and finally in the seed method of a database initializer:

```
public  class DatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<PeopleContext>
{
  protected override void Seed(PeopleContext context)
  {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE SystemUserAccounts ADD CONSTRAINT uc_User UNIQUE(UserId)"); 
  }
}
```

Then just call your DatabaseInitializer in your program:

```
  Database.SetInitializer<PeopleContext>(new DatabaseInitializer());
```

This gives me the table structure shown in the OP.  I am not sure how it will behave in queries yet.

I hope it helps anyone that is trying to do this.

Tal

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're going for - but I think what you're wanting is 3 main classes - `User`, `UserAccount` and `AccountRole`, with a many to many relationship table of UserAccountRole, that's just mapping the UserAccounts to the AccountRoles.  If I'm mistaken in understanding your goal, please update the question with more specifics.

If so, I accomplished this with these classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserAccount UserAccount { get; set; }
}

public class UserAccount
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AccountRole> AccountRoles { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

}

public class AccountRole
{
    public int AccountRoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

and this mapping:

```
public class Model : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AccountRole> AccountRoles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional(u => u.UserAccount)
            .WithRequired(ua => ua.User);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>()
            .HasKey(k => new {k.AccountId, k.UserId});

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>()
            .HasMany(ua => ua.AccountRoles)
            .WithMany(ar => ar.UserAccounts)
            .Map(map =>
                {
                    map.ToTable("UserAccountRole");
                    map.MapLeftKey("UserId", "AccountId");
                    map.MapRightKey("AccountRoleId");
                });

    }
}
```

This created the classes, as well as the many to many table with the composite key you're looking for:

[image]

Comment: My question is not so much how to get the many to many as you have shown, I have that.  I am trying to get the 1=>1,0 between User and UserAccount.  Your solution, and mine as well, create a many to many on the UserAccount table.

Comment: When I looked in my database, this also create a FK relationship between UserAccount -> User.  The first mapping of user, creating an optional to UserAccount, required user created this.  It created a new FK of User_UserId on the UserAccount table due to the navigation relationship of UserAccount on the User class.  If you don't need that, the relationship is created properly using UserId part of the composite key.  Does that work for you?

Comment: I am going to edit the OP with an image of the db I am trying to get